# Iterate over a list of IPv6 Addresse in a Bash Script for loop

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ipv6, scp

In a Bash Script I iterate over a list of IPv6 Addresses. I try to scp a unique file on each unique IPv6 Device. The unique file for every Device has the IPv6 Address in the filename.

Unfortunately SSH/SCP try to resolve something in the Filename and throw this Error:

"ssh: Could not resolve hostname file_2001: Name or service not known"

How can I supress this unexpected resolving? or is there a possibility to escape something in here?

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVICES="\
2001:db8::3e81:d8ff:feef:4982 \
"

do_copy_xml_file()
{
    if [ -e $XML_FILE ]; then
        for X in ${DEVICES} ; do
            echo "copy file_${X}.xml to ${X}:/data/file.sxml"
            sshpass scp -o stricthostkeychecking=yes file_"${X}".xml root@\[${X}\]:/file.xml
        done
    else
        echo $XML_FILE does not exist
    fi
}

do_copy_xml_file
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/14411/95973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
file_"${X//:/_}".xml
```

in order to replace all `:` with `_`.

If your files are already named this way and this shouldn't change,

```
file_"${X//:/\\:}".xml
```

can be used as well. But I'm not sure if `scp` does recognize this appropriately.

Besides that, the `scp` manpage contains

> File names may contain a user and host specification to indicate that
>   the file is to be copied to/from that host. Local file names can be
>   made explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp
>   treating file names containing ':' as host specifiers. Copies between
>   two remote hosts are also permitted.

So just using `./file_"${X}".xml` should work as well.

Comment: The replacement with _ works for me. The second approach would be nicer but it doesn't work. I got the Error ssh: Could not resolve hostname file_2001\\: Name or service not known

Comment: @OliverG. I just found something potentially useful in the `scp` manpage.

Comment: Thank you that ./file_"${X}".xml help!